# When $G$ is such that every subgroup is normal, then $N_G(x) \not= \{e\}$ where $x \in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question has appeared exactly as is in two or three past exams, I'm confused by the notation. Am I to find the normalizer of $\langle x \rangle $ in $G$ or the centralizer of $x$ in G? In both cases I get that if $G\not=\{e\}$ then the result is true.

Comment: Usually, when you write $N_G(x)$, it means $N_G(\langle x\rangle)$, the normaliser of the subgroup $\langle x\rangle$. Therefore you are right, the normaliser is $G$ itself and if $G\neq 1$ the result follows (the centraliser notation is different, the centraliser of $x\in G$ is denoted by $C_G(x)$ and it is always non-trivial for any $x\in G$, thus there is nothing to prove again).

Comment: But it is possible that $N_G(x)$ means the normalizer of the element $x$, which is what is usually written as the centralizer $C_G(x)$ of $x$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you mean that $N_G(x)$ may be used to denote $N_G(\{x\})=C_G(x)$?

Comment: I don't know - I was just speculating on possible meanings!

Comment: The condition that every subgroup is normal is not even necessary, we always have that $x^x=x$.